# Kusto:How to expand dynamic type to separate row without duplicate?

Tags: kql

I had read two datetime columns from table and convert that column to list for iteration.

```
let start_time = toscalar(Mytable| where Vin == '3ALMHLDR9MSMN4183'| summarize make_list (Start_Time));
let end_time = toscalar( Mytable| where Vin == '3ALMHLDR9MSMN4183'| summarize make_list (End_Time));
```

Now, I looping this two list on anther table.

```
Test
| mv-expand start_time =split(start_time, ",") to typeof(datetime )
|where  Timestamp >=start_time and Timestamp <=end_time
```

But,While expanding the start time it did multiplication (means records are duplicate )n*n

help me avoid this duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could achieve that as follows:

```
let times = toscalar(
    Mytable
    | where Vin == '3ALMHLDR9MSMN4183'
    | summarize make_list(pack_array(Start_Time, End_Time))
);
Test
| where Vin == '3ALMHLDR9MSMN4183'
| mv-apply t = times on (
    where Timestamp between(todatetime(times[0]) .. todatetime(times[1]))
    | take 1
)
| project-away t
```